# Delete <83> and <91> char non printable characters

Tags: unix

I need delete some Characters in my file like <83> or <91>. These are non printable characters and i dont know how i can delete it.

I work in Unix and I am using sed command but I dont find the solutions

One example:

CORUA<83>Á<91>A

Comment: That looks like UTF-8 encoding, and deleting the odd characters will not be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

U can use this command to remove unprintable chars but I am not sure what u meant by <83> and <91>

> tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < file-with-binary-chars > clean-file

other links are

http://www.asciitable.com/

http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~tway/resources/ascii-table.html

Comment: When i use Vi the text appears with this simbols in blue font. But when i use the command head appears with �. I use your command but in someone lines delete the Ñ char

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
tr -d '\x83\x91' yourFile > newFile
```

Comment: Dont delete nothing

Comment: muzido, you need to add some context to your answer as well as the raw code. Some explanation of how this works, and how you think it will provide a solution, will be helpful both to the original questioner and to any other user looking for solutions to similar problems. It will also stop your answer from being automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.

Answer (score 0):

```
strings inputfile > outputfile
```